# NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' (used in the 'TestComponent' component template)

Tags: angular, webpack

---

First of, yes I looked into all the other related issues where everyone says the issue has been solved elsewhere! (they pretty much all boil down to not adding the component to the module's `declarations`, but I *do* have it there. or to add either `BrowserModule` or `CommonModule` to imports (NgModule imports), and I have them both now. I'm thoroughly stumped...

---

I've been stuck on this for a while, and the annoying thing is that this *almost* works, but it doesn't quite... and I've gotten other angular projects up and running, but this is a minimal example of a bigger angular project that I'm working on so I'm looking for a pointer to where the problem lies that causes this error. any help is appreciated!

This might be a webpack issue... I don't really know at the moment, and I don't want to assume anything, Hence I included it as a tag.

I have made a minimal example app... not sure where the best way to host it for stack overflow purposes, so here's a zip on dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pjsynyqdnw6wim7/angular-app.tgz?dl=0

So you can download, unzip and run `npm i` + `npm run build` + host files with `python3 -m http.server` or similar...

for the sake of making this more available (maybe someone will see something right away), here's some files from the repo:

main.ts

```js
import './polyfills';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from "./modules/app.module";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});

// platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

modules/app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { TestComponent } from '../components/test.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, CommonModule],
  declarations: [TestComponent],
  bootstrap: [TestComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

components/test.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-component',
  template: /*html*/`
    <div *ngFor="let foobar of foobars">
      {{ foobar }}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class TestComponent { 
  public foobars = ['foobar1', 'foobar2', 'foobar42']
}
```

polyfills.ts

```js
import 'core-js';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js';
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script src='./dist/app-bundle.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <test-component></test-component>
</body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: {
    app : './src/main.ts'
  },
  output: {
    filename: "./[name]-bundle.js",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          compact: false,
          plugins: ['@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel'],
        },
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  target: "web",
  devtool: "source-map",
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
}
```

Comment: If I add your component to stackblitz, it works as expected. I've never created a custom webpack config for an angular project, so I cannot say something about that. If I get errors where I cannot find the origin, I sometimes setup a new angular project from scratch and then add part by part of tha failing project to look when the error occur. Maybe this could help here, too?

Comment: something is not right with the webpack config. most likely you haven't set up agnular compilet plugin. is there any reason you are using custom project skeleton instead of angular-cli generated one?

Comment: @Andrei
The main project was angularjs, and I'm migrating it to angular, and to do that I decided to follow the guide by Jawache on youtube https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-TLnxxt_AVE9dec6IU-0DSx6Oy5hsTCu. I figure using webpack isn't that normal for angular projects?

I'll try replacing with the angular-cli generated skeleton soon, at least that gives me an actionable! (I've been kinda at a loss for ideas lately)

Comment: @MatterOfFact yeah, this is what I've been doing to generate the minimal example, I started from scratch and added things line by line. At least I'm glad I got the same error twice doing the same thing. otherwise the error would be more elusive!